# Get the a variable defined in the command running python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this script named test.py:

```
import os

print(os.environ['LOL'])
```

That I run as follow :

> (LOL=HAHAHA; python3 test.py)

But it raises a KeyError because it can't find the variable LOL.

I also tried with :

```
os.getenv('LOL')
```

But it just returns None.

How can I access to the variable LOL in this context.

Comment: have you set the variable in the first place?

Comment: I believe I did yes. When I'm doing LOL=HAHAHA

Comment: try print(os.environ) see if you have LOL there

Comment: export LOL=HAHAHAHA should do the trick

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Try removing the semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supplement the environment variables for the command during which you invoke `python3 test.py` as follows

```
$ LOL=HAHAHA python3 test.py
HAHAHA
$ env LOL=HAHAHA python3 test.py
HAHAHA
$ echo $LOL
<empty string>
```

or you can export the variable for the current session as:

```
$ export LOL=HAHAHA
$ python3 test.py
HAHAHA
$ echo $LOL
HAHAHA
```

---

Simply doing `LOL=HAHAHA; python3 test.py` doesn't work because that just sets the `LOL=HAHAHA` variable for the shell process.

Another thing to note, the first approach shown only sets the environment variable for that specific command. It does not set it in the environment. Doing it with the export instead, sets it for the environment. You can see the difference in the values of `$LOL` above

Comment: It works, how is (LOL=HAHAHAp; python3 test.py) different from what you suggested?

Comment: `LOL=HAHAHA` only sets it for the current process (aka the shell). `export` exports it for the session and `LOL=HAHAHA python3 test.py` invokes only that command with the specific environment variables

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an environmental variable, so if you are on windows to set it you need to do something like:

```
set LOL=HAHAHAHA
```

Then you should be able to access it. To make sure it was set correctly you can also just run:

```
set
```

To get a full list of environmental variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just export the variable, i.e. run the command with:

```
export LOL=HAHA; python3 test.py
```

or set `LOL` in the same command, i.e. without the semicolon:

```
LOL=HAHA python3 test.py
```

---

Content of `test.py`:

```
import os


print(os.environ['LOL'])
```